# laravel multi-field search form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

have a multi-field search form in my Laravel 5.2 app

```
price 
rooms 
type 
rent
```

i have some thing wrong my result no correct i think because im using  orWhere(). i want AND between input fields. i want any solution for this

```
public function search()
    {

        $un_price = \Request::get('un_price');
        $un_rooms = \Request::get('un_rooms');
        $un_type = \Request::get('un_type');
        $un_rent = \Request::get('un_rent');
        $units = DB::table('units')->whereIn('un_status', [1])
            ->where('un_price','like','%'.$un_price.'%')
            ->orWhere("un_rooms", "LIKE", "%$un_rooms%")
            ->orWhere("un_type", "LIKE", "%$un_type%")
            ->orWhere("un_rent", "LIKE", "%$un_rent%")
            ->paginate(20);
        return view('home.units.show', compact('units'));
}
```

Comment: just use where instead of orWhere then?

Comment: when i use where only i get nothing

Comment: concat variables with % mark in orWhere fields like in your where field, otherwise you are searching for "un_rooms like '%$un_rooms%'"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use query string filtering. Do something like this:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $unit = (new Unit)->newQuery(); //where Unit is the model
    if($request->has('un_price'){
        $unit->where('un_price',$request->un_price)
    }
    if($request->has('un_rooms'){
        $unit->where('un_rooms',$request->un_rooms)
    }
    //go on until the end
    $units = $unit->get();
    return view('home.units.show', compact('units'));
}
```

This way you get all the result that you need depending on the inputs that you receive.

Comment: with this case how can i search between un_price and add two input fields un_price_from and un_price_to

Comment: elseif ($request->has('un_price_from','un_price_to')){
            $unit->whereBetween('un_price', [$request->un_price_from, $request->un_price_to]);
        }